# How to manually install npm in Windows?

Tags: node.js, npm

We may download `.msi` files from [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) and install as normal windows application.  This shall install both `node.exe` and `npm` in system.

In a development environment, I wish to install various version of `node` and `npm` in my machine.

I know how to download and install `node.exe` manually from [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/).  But I couldn't find a way to download `npm` for Windows manually and extract in the folder I want.

Answer (score 3):

Per [npm doc](https://github.com/npm/npm#windows-install-or-upgrade)

> You can download a zip file from https://github.com/npm/npm/releases, and unpack it in the `node_modules\npm\` folder inside node's installation folder.
>
> To upgrade to `npm 2`, follow the Windows upgrade instructions in the npm Troubleshooting Guide:
>
> https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Node Version Manager`](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) for windows to use different versions of `node.js`.

Also, you can use, [NVMW](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw),